# Bug? System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid

Tags: c#, .net-core, uri

The strings are identical but when passed as a variable it is not valid?

What the hell is going on? Is it a language bug? I'm running this in C# .Net Core

```
var postUrl = "​http://www.contoso.com";
var postUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com"); // works
var uri = new Uri(postUrl); // does not work
```

Answer (score 8):

If you pulling your hair, then it because there is space after first opening quote in postUrl. Please remove that space & your bug will be begone.
[image]

Comment: Sharp eye! In fact, this is a Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)

Answer (score 0):

Worked around the problem by using.

```
var postUrl = "​http://www.contoso.com";
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(postUrl);
var uri = uriBuilder.Uri
```

Still wondering wtf?

Just the daily wtf of a programmer doing his job.